# General login page for all websites

Tags: magento-1.8, login, websites

I have 4 websites within 1 Magento instance. Is it possible to have 1 general login page and magento will then detect which website the customer belongs to and redirects them to the correct one.

At the moment Magento is only letting customers sign in if they click the login from the relevant website.

Answer (score 1):

The global login should work if you share the customers on global level and not on website level.

You can adjust your setting here:
Set the Account Sharing Options in `System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration` to global and this should work.

Anyway, I am not sure if this solves the redirect issue then.